# Is there a way to filter the command history in Windows using cmder?

Tags: windows, grep, cmder

In Linux I can doing something like `history | grep abc` and that will only bring up the commands that start with 'abc'. With Windows in cmder, I can bring up the history of commands with the `history` command, but I can't find a way to filter it down by the first few letters of the command. There seems to be no equivalent of `|` and `grep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat %CMDER_ROOT%\config\.history | grep abc`

In Cmder::Cmder sessions history is a doskey macro. The output of a macro cannot be passed using the pipe | but you could use the command that is the content of the doskey macro.

Referenced: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1770